# Deprecated methods in wxBitmap?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

When using wxWidgets 3.1 I get the following deprecation warnings with wxBitmap:

```
'wxGDIImage::SetWidth': was declared deprecated
'wxGDIImage::SetHeight': was declared deprecated
```

As I can't find a suitable hint at the related position in sourcecode: what is the replacement for this? How shall one set width and height of a bitmap now?

Answer (score 3):

[dimensions and depth can only be set at construction time](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_bitmap.html#a0091921ee85f7444e846e6183ec64909), and the [commit](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/26ee45e4a55270c79cbe0b691288d8d235626aca).
AFAIU using those functions never changed the bitmap structure, so using them will only be misleading.

If you want to go further and not even allow deprecated functions, you can build your libs and app with `WXWIN_COMPATIBILITY_3_0` set to `0`.

Comment: OK, sounds reasonable. But what is the best way to invalidate an existing wxBitmap then (assumed some other image data have to be set later)?

Comment: Create a new `wxBitmap` with the new image data and replace the old one.